# Override CSS class of a custom child component in Angular

Tags: angular

**Angular 16**
**SCSS**

Given a parent component template referencing a custom component with it's own css class in default ViewEncapsulation mode are these my only options to have the parent change the foo css class to have a background-color property of blue.

1. ng-deep /deep/ (deprecated, or soon to be, allegedly)
2. Use @Input with Custom Comp and pass in some variable to key off which can toggle ngClass to a different class with a blue background depending on the value
3. Use scss variables in custom-comp that can be overriden by the parent component css
4. I don't think I can use [style.foo.background]="'red'" given it's a class I'm trying to effect change on

Are these the only options available to tackle this problem?

**parent component template**

```
<custom-comp></custom-comp>
```

**custom-comp.scss**

```
.foo
{
   background-color:red;
}
```